# Why `daterange` showing invalid date?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iis, bootstrap-4

I am using  `daterange`  picker on my asp MVC application, when i am developing the picker was worked very well, but when i go to production and put my application on `IIS` the  `daterange` is not working and giving me `invalid date`

[image: the image desplaying the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According t oyour description, I suggest you could try to follow below steps to modify the IIS application

1. Open IIS management console
2. Select your website
3. Open .NET GLOBALIZATION

[image]

4. From Culture tab, select required Culture and UI Culture.

[image]

5. Re-start your IIS application